# How to install Numpy and Scipy to python 2.7.5 when system thinks that it already installed (but on python 2.6)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I've installed and set as default python 2.7.5 instead of 2.6.9 (I think). The thing is I can't install numpy, scipy and other modules via

```
sudo apt-get install python-*
```

It says that that they were already installed (which I really did for 2.6.9) but python 2.7.5 doesn't know of these modules. Please help. I know that I shouldn't uninstall 2.6.9, but I really need those modules

Comment: Use `apt-get` with force install. I don't use linux so not sure which option is that. Perhaps it's `--reinstall`!! like `sudo apt-get --reinstall numpy`

Comment: If you want to use the standard Ubuntu packages, you should be running Python 2.7.6 (not 2.7.5), and installing numpy and scipy should straightforward (as you expect).  I can't find Python 2.6 packages in 12.04 or 14.04 - how did you install it? (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python2.6&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all )

Comment: Yeah, thanks, Rory. It appeared that 2.7.6 was already installed and they began to fight with each other. So I deleted it, got my unity and a dozen of apps crashed, but I managed to reinstall those, so I got that going for me which is nice. edit: I blame myself for my troubles